# Http requests throw XMLHttpRequest error for flutter web

Tags: http, flutter, get, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web

I am creating a rss feed reader web application using flutter web. This app makes calls to public rss feeds provided by different providers.

I am using Http get to make a call and it throws **XMLHttpRequest** error.

I am unable to get any response. Could you kindly let me know how to resolve this error and get the response?

eg: of rss feed used is https://www.space.com/feeds/all

Note: When tested the same on mobile, it works fine and provides the response.

Thanks

---

Pasted below is the code that is being used

```dart
//Fetching the feed data for the given url
  Future<List<FeedItemDetails>> fetchFeedItemList(String category, String url) async {
    print("Calling URL : $url");
    http.Response response = await http
        .get(url)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: Constants.NETWORK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<FeedItemDetails> feedItemList = List<FeedItemDetails>();

      switch (_getFeedType(response.body)) {
        case Constants.FEED_TYPE_RSS:
          {

            //Parsing the RSS feed from the response
            RssFeed rssFeed = RssFeed.parse(response.body);
            //Keeping the image of feed for adding in FeedItemDetails,
            String rssImageURL = rssFeed.image == null ? "" : rssFeed.image.url;
            feedItemList = rssFeed.items
                .map((item) => FeedItemDetails.parseRSSItem(item,category,rssImageURL))
                .toList();
          }
          break;
        case Constants.FEED_TYPE_ATOM:
          {
            //Parsing the RSS feed from the response
            AtomFeed atomFeed = AtomFeed.parse(response.body);
            //Keeping the logo of feed for adding in FeedItemDetails,
            String atomImageURL = atomFeed.logo == null ? "" : atomFeed.logo;
            feedItemList = atomFeed.items
                .map(
                    (item) => FeedItemDetails.parseAtomItem(item,category, atomImageURL))
                .toList();
          }
          break;
        default:
          {
            throw Exception(Constants.INVALID_FEED_DATA);
          }
      }
      return feedItemList;
    } else {
      // If service call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception(Constants.INVALID_RESPONSE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: please share with us your code, efforts and the way you try so far.

Comment: Updated the question with the code being used for making http.get call

Comment: thank you. it helps others to answer your question.

Comment: Can you post the version of `http` package you use and also the console log for the error.